# net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on http POST to express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, ssl

I'm trying to post from a react client to an express server on localhost and I get this error in google chrome.

react app: http://localhost:3000
express app: http://localhost:5000

```
POST https://localhost:5000/upload net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I don't have any SSL https self signed certificate, but do I need to? I have used create-react-app inside a directory within my express application to bootstrap my front-end so I'm unaware if maybe a webpack setting somewhere is trying to handle http as https for this particular operation?

I haven't used any bootstrapping for my express js application and I'll include my server file below for reference.

```
const express = require ('express')
const bodyParser = require ('body-parser')
const port = 5000

var app = express()
var cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors())
app.use(bodyParser())
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))



app.post('/upload', (req,res)=>{
    if (req.files === null ){
        return res.status(400).json({message: 'no image uploaded please try again'})
    }else{
        const file = req.files.file
        let body = req.body
        res.json({body})
    } 
})
```

I know there are a fair few questions on this issue but they weren't relevant or didn't provide me any insight. I have tried making sure the ports are allowed through my firewall aswell. I have also cleared my browser cache.

Comment: _"I don't have any SSL https self signed certificate, but do I need to?"_ **Short Answer:** yes. **Long Answer:** You'll need a self-signed certificate for your localhost environment and will need to add it to your `Windows` certificate store (if you're using _Microsoft Windows_). Without the certificate added in your certificate store, you will still receive an error message that the certificate was signed by a _Certificate Authority_ that could not be verified. Once you deploy to a production environment, you'll want to use a certificate from a valid CA (free through _Let's Encrypt_ or paid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed in multiple posts

By default you cannot call localhost request on browsers but you can disable the security

Check here : [Disable same origin policy in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)

Comment: Thank You! I was unaware of that principle rule.

Comment: No, you can definitely use `localhost`.  And, same-origin policy isn't the problem here.  Using HTTPS on an HTTP-only server is.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and changed the URL to **`http://localhost:5000/upload`** instead of using https://localhost:5000/upload.

Comment: I have done same mistake, My issues resolved by removed s in https

Answer (score 1):

i replaced const API_URL = 'https://localhost:8000';

by const API_URL = 'http://localhost:8000';

Comment: Please note, there is already an accepted answer. Read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), thank you

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but it was with WAGMI (react hooks for web3 dev) and instead of using "https://localhost:6969" (this was the RPC url for my local node) I used "http://localhost:6969" which worked!